# Get only some part from JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a Json value that I want to get only some part of it and ignore the other keys.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    public Order order{ get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Order
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    public int orderNo{ get; set; }
    public Customer customer{ get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<MyClass> orderDetails= orderResult.Select(_ => new MyClass
              {
                 order= _.order
              }).ToList();

JArray res = JArray.FromObject(orderDetails);
```

res returns this:

> {[ { "id": null, "order": { "id": 3, "orderNo": 12, "customer": { "id": 1 } } } ]}

But I want to get only this part:

> {[ { "id": null, "order": { "id": 3 } ]}

Comment: You can add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the property which you want to ignore, Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple approaches here. Use `JsonIgnore` attribute on fields you don't need:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int orderNo{ get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Customer customer{ get; set; }
}
```

That will affect all usages thoug.

Create classes only with needed fields and map to them:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    public OrderDTO order{ get; set; }
}
public class OrderDTO
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
}

List<MyClass> orderDetails= orderResult
    .Select(o => new MyClass
    {
        order = new OrderDTO
        {
            id = o.id
        }
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or just using anonymous types:

```
var orderDetails = orderResult
    .Select(o => new
    {
        id = (long?)null,
        order = new
        {
            o.id
        }
    })
    .ToList();
```

P.S.

Use [Common C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), in this case [Pascal casing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#pascal-case) for public properties. If you want to affect the serialization (i.e. use other convention then used for C#) there are multiple ways to achieve that in Newtonsoft Json.NET - you can use [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySkipSpecifiedNames.htm) or manually define property names via `JsonProperty` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I did it with creating a DTO class like second approach, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make a modification in Myclass

```
public class MyClass{
   public long? id { get; set; }
   public int orderNo{ get; set; }
}
```

and to the code block

```
    List<MyClass> orderDetails= orderResult.Select(_ => new MyClass
                  {id=_.order.id
                     order= _.order.orderNo
                  }).ToList();


JArray res = JArray.FromObject(orderDetails);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it returns like this {[
  {
    "id": null,
    "order": 8
  }
]} and I need a json like this {[ { "id": null, "order": { "id": 3 } ]} . Is it possible?